# Is it natural to say "Our turn hasn't come yet"?

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-structure

When I looked up the noun "**turn**" in some dictionaries, I saw people use the dummy subject "**it**" with "**turn**".

For example,

**Is it my turn yet?**

**It’s your turn. Roll the dice.**

**Whose turn is it?**

I am not sure if it is natural to say "**Our turn hasn't come yet**" which was literally translated from my mother tongue?

Also, we often use "**yet**" with the perfect tenses.

So, I am not sure if we can say "**Has it been my turn yet?**" or "**It hasn't been my turn yet.**"?

Comment: I don't understand why you're asking this, or how exactly it differs from "proofreading". There are many written instances of ["Our turn hasn't come yet"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Our+turn+hasn%27t+come+yet%22) (even more for ["**My** turn hasn't come yet"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22My+turn+hasn%27t+come+yet%22)) in Google Books. Obviously you need a slightly contrived context for ***Has it been my turn yet?***, but that's just because a "player" would normally *know* that. I can't see what would make you think those sentences might *not* be valid / natural.

Comment: If you say, to be someone's turn, you can use any tense that works with a copular verb.

Comment: "Our turn hasn't come yet," feels slightly formal to me for playing a board game, so I would prefer "It's not our turn yet." That said, there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *our turn hasn't come yet*, you would probably say:

> It's not our turn yet.

You typically **have** a turn, so instead of *it hasn't been my turn yet*, you would probably say:

> I haven't had a turn yet.

Instead of *has it been my turn yet?*, you would probably say:

> Have I had a turn yet? or

> Is it my turn?

Comment: Does this sound naturally "it hasn't come to my turn yet" instead of "my turn hasn't come yet"?

Comment: No.  You more often have a turn than a turn comes to you. You would probably say "It's not my turn yet" or "I haven't had a turn yet" or "When is my turn?"

Comment: But this sentence is from the dictionary "By the time it came to my turn to sing, I was a bag of nerves."

Comment: It really depends on the context. The sentence from the dictionary is more formal than the examples i gave. You could also say, "When it was my turn to sing...", which would be a little more informal and probably more common in spoken, everyday English.